# Uneven timestep with java.swing.Timer and java.util.Timer and Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, animation, timer, sleep

I can't understand why this Timer is animating jaggedly. Is this a platform-dependent problem? I'm writing a 2D game using this kind of animation and am frustrated with the uneven frame rate. Here's the code for a simplified example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimationTest extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Point location = new Point(0, 300);
    private int speed = 3;

    public AnimationTest()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    }

    public void timeStep()
    {
        move();
        repaint();
        currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(currentTime - previousTime);
        previousTime = currentTime;
    }

    private void move()
    {
        location.x += speed;
        if(location.x >= 800) location.x = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        g2d.fillOval(location.x, location.y, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

And here's the main method:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class AnimationTestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        final AnimationTest test = new AnimationTest();
        frame.add(test);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int animationMethod = 0;

        if(animationMethod == 0)
        {
            new javax.swing.Timer(10, new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    test.timeStep();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        else if(animationMethod == 1)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        test.timeStep();
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
        else if(animationMethod == 2)
        {
            java.util.Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        test.timeStep();
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Modifying the animationMethod variable doesn't change much of the result. You can see the uneven frame rate in the nanosecond printouts. Help!

Comment: How uneven is it...? Can you give a sample printout?

Comment: Where's the CPU time being spent when it hiccoughs? Is it happening whenever a buffer is flushed?  Is there any operation (besides animation) you can do with a timer scheduled like that that isn't bursty?

Comment: 15629506
15588454
15626427
15554074
15493521
15623861
15574086
15766004
17558948
15506351
15673636
16722515
15402694
15936369
15368313
15617191
15583323
15569980
15657217
15632071
15565363
15488390
15497113
15611033
15612059
15562797
15736241
15469916
15672611
15712123
15665940
15637716
15516614
15593585
15581784
15605388
15600256
15644388
15538678
15536113
15845542
15413470
15583836
15648493

Comment: Are you on a single-user system with adequate configuration and no CPU demanding background jobs hogging the CPUs and cores?

Comment: The differences seem like a very small % of the total time of each interval, so that seems like minor noise. Something else must be happening to make it jagged.

Comment: The greatest difference there is about 2ms. Remember that those times are in nanoseconds. I would say that's pretty good... Is the animation visibly jumpy or are the times your only basis?

Comment: @Radiodef, just imagine if he was measuring it in yoctoseconds!

Comment: If you run the code, the filledOval jerks as it's animated which probably indicates bursts... Task Manager says my CPU is running at 0% and I'm the only user.

Comment: Are you using standard graphics buffering techniques for efficiency? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering

Comment: @Radiodef yes it's visibly jumpy

Comment: In any case, if you are trying to measure the frame rate, what you should be timing is `paintComponent`, not the update thread. The painting is asynchronous so it doesn't happen immediately after you call `repaint`.

Comment: So the moving of objects in the scene (in this case the oval) and rendering should be in different threads?

Answer (score 0):

the swing timer is the most unprecise option you got.

There are 2 other options:

- The Utility Timer (medium precision)
- Own Thread (highest precision)

Check out [this link](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/).

If you choose to make an own thread, check out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwjZDfcQ7Rc) for the game loop.